# How can I download Adobe Connect videos to mp4 or speed up listening?

Tags: video, download, adobe-connect

How can I download Adobe Connect videos to mp4 or speed up listening?

Ideas:

1. Hack my computer in some way so as to make the video playback faster by making time pass faster in the CPU or something for this Chrome Flash Player application. I think this is possible for the video at least, and for the sound, I hope this will not change its pitch. My OS is a Debian-based version of Linux.
2. Screen record the whole thing, but this would still be tedious since it would require me to have a dedicated computer running for that, I couldn't do something else at the same time.
3. Download the videos by using the existing `/output/filename.zip?download=zip` hack that is to append this to the URL. But this results in a zip file full of 17 (or more) harsh `.flv` and `.xml` files containing separated audio and video. I searched for a tool to convert those back to the regular video, and I haven't found anything useful. I found that those annoying and harsh files are the same than the ones that are already downloaded in the browser's cache for the playback.
4. Ask every professor to unlock the mp4 download such as enabling the possibility of using `/output/filename.mp4?download=mp4` with `download=mp4` rather than a harsh zip file. But I fear that this would require them to allow their video to be publicly accessible by anyone in their admin settings, so I'm not sure this is an option for them.

Comment: This is more of a question for Superuser, so I'm voting to close and move to SU.

Comment: Can it be moved in some way? I don't want to do cross-posting.

Comment: I mean, how can it be moved?

Comment: One more close vote, and it should happen.

Comment: I'd imagine that viewing the of the videos is recorded in the back-end of the Connect system and tracked to confirm viewing. Downloading the videos would likely prevent this confirmation. You would need to contact the institution's IT people regarding getting the videos, and the instructors and course monitors regarding confirming that you've watched it.

Comment: Confirming to watch the video isn't required (and I don't watch them most of the time already)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume that the Adobe Connect ID is p6vwxp2d0c2f, i.e. the URL is https://my.adobeconnect.com/p6vwxp2d0c2f. As you mentioned in the question, you can add `/output/p6vwxp2d0c2f.zip?download=zip` at the end of the URL to download some zip archive containing a bunch of audio and video files as well as some .xml files. E.g., https://my.adobeconnect.com/p6vwxp2d0c2e/output/p6vwxp2d0c2e.zip?download=zip could contain:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\[...]\p6vwxp2d0c2f

02/09/2019  11:27 AM    <DIR>          .
02/09/2019  11:27 AM    <DIR>          ..
02/09/2019  11:00 AM        52,239,473 cameraVoip_1_11.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM         1,364,573 cameraVoip_1_11.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM         7,176,904 cameraVoip_1_15.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM           188,012 cameraVoip_1_15.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             6,004 cameraVoip_1_3.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             1,698 cameraVoip_1_3.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM        62,603,505 cameraVoip_1_7.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM         1,625,383 cameraVoip_1_7.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             2,249 ftcontent1.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             8,219 ftcontent1.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM            25,685 ftcontent13.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM            85,464 ftcontent13.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM           199,781 ftcontent5.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM           657,091 ftcontent5.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM           182,297 ftcontent9.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM           601,758 ftcontent9.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             1,354 fttitle0.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             3,272 fttitle0.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             1,354 fttitle12.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             3,298 fttitle12.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             1,354 fttitle4.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             3,290 fttitle4.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             1,354 fttitle8.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             3,298 fttitle8.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM         1,815,158 indexstream.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM         7,703,603 indexstream.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM         5,316,597 mainstream.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM        21,259,001 mainstream.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM       217,448,561 screenshare_2_10.flv
02/09/2019  11:01 AM         1,364,572 screenshare_2_10.xml
02/09/2019  11:01 AM        32,364,457 screenshare_2_14.flv
02/09/2019  11:01 AM           188,011 screenshare_2_14.xml
02/09/2019  11:01 AM           387,981 screenshare_2_2.flv
02/09/2019  11:01 AM             1,698 screenshare_2_2.xml
02/09/2019  11:01 AM       237,470,572 screenshare_2_6.flv
02/09/2019  11:01 AM         1,625,385 screenshare_2_6.xml
02/09/2019  11:01 AM                48 telephony-files.xml
02/09/2019  11:01 AM               691 transcriptstream.flv
02/09/2019  11:01 AM             2,391 transcriptstream.xml
              39 File(s)    653,935,396 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   1,590,358,016 bytes free
```

- cameraVoip_*_*.xml contains the audio + webcam if any.
- screenshare_*_*.xml contains the audio + webcam if any.

To merge them, you can use `ffmpeg` (I took the `ffmpeg` commands from Oliver Wang / Yannick Hold-Geoffroy / Aaron Hertzmann):

```
ffmpeg -i cameraVoip_1_11.flv -i screenshare_2_10.flv -c copy -map 0:a:0 -map 1:v:0 -shortest output.flv
```

where:

- `-map 0:a:0`: map the first input file to be used just for the audio.
- `-map 1:v:0`: map the second input file to be used just for the video.
- `-shortest`: cut the audio or video in case cameraVoip_1_11.flv and screenshare_2_10.flv don't have the same length.

If you want to keep the webcam video and place it in some corner of the video screen sharing:

```
ffmpeg -i cameraVoip_1_11.flv -i screenshare_2_10.flv  \
                         -filter_complex \
                         "color=s=1072x480:c=black [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x480 [upperleft]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=432x240 [upperright]; [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]; [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=640" \
                         -c:v libx264 -c:a mp2 output.mkv
```

---

Regarding mapping the cameraVoip_*_*.xml to the correct screenshare_*_*.xml, in case there is more than one:

One could look at the cameraVoip_*_*.xml / screenshare_*_*.xml to get the timestamps of when the audio / screen share video began. This allows to map the screenshare_*_*.xml with the correct cameraVoip_*_*.xml.

E.g., in https://my.adobeconnect.com/p6vwxp2d0c2f/output/p6vwxp2d0c2f.zip?download=zip, from cameraVoip_1_11.xml, line 21:

```
<String><![CDATA[Thu Feb 07 21:11:23 2019]]></String>
```

Otherwise, another way could be to sort cameraVoip_*_*.xml / screenshare_*_*.xml, then map the first cameraVoip_*_*.xml with the first screenshare_*_*.xml, the second cameraVoip_*_*.xml with the first screenshare_*_*.xml, etc. I don't know if it'd break in some cases (seems to be ok for the couple of Adobe Connect recordings I looked at but perhaps that's because people always share screens).

---

I wrote some python script to automate the process (code repo: https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/adobe-connect-video-downloader):

```
'''
Requirements:
- python 2.7 or 3
- wget, unzip, and ffmpeg accessible from command line.

Examples:
python connect2vid_v2.py https://my.adobeconnect.com/pqc06mcawjgn/  --output_filename=" Understanding how the Network impacts your service"

Please email Franck Dernoncourt <franck.dernoncourt@gmail.com> if you improve this code.
'''

import shlex
import subprocess
import os
import glob
import argparse
import sys
import re


def run_command(command):
    print('running command: {0}'.format(command))
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        print(output.strip())
        if output == b'' and process.poll() is not None:
            print('Done running the command.')
            break
        if output:
            print(output.strip())
    rc = process.poll()
    return rc

def create_folder_if_not_exists(directory):
    '''
    Create the folder if it doesn't exist already.
    '''
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

def extract_connect_id(parser, args):
    '''
    Function written by Aaron Hertzmann
    '''
    # ----- extract the connectID or ZIP file  -----

    if len(args.URLorIDorZIP) < 1:
    #    print('Error: No Connect recording URL provided.')
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(0)

    if args.URLorIDorZIP[0][-4:].lower() == '.zip':
        sourceZIP = args.URLorIDorZIP[0]
        connectID = os.path.basename(sourceZIP[:-4])
    elif len(args.URLorIDorZIP[0]) == 12:
        connectID = args.URLorIDorZIP[0]
    else:
        s = args.URLorIDorZIP[0].split('/')
        connectID = None
        for i in range(len(s)-1):
            if 'adobeconnect.com' in s[i]:
                connectID = s[i+1]
                break
        if connectID == None:
            print("Error: couldn't parse URL")
            sys.exit(1)

    return connectID


def main():
    '''
    This is the main function
    '''

    # ================ parse the arguments (part of the parsing code was written by Aaron Hertzmann) ======================

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Download an Adobe Connect recording and convert to a video file.')
    parser.add_argument('URLorIDorZIP', nargs='*', help='URL, code, or ZIP file for the Connect recording')
    parser.add_argument('--output_folder',default='output_videos',help='Folder for output files')
    parser.add_argument('--output_filename',default='noname', help='output_filename')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    #main_output_folder = "all_videos"
    main_output_folder = args.output_folder
    output_filename = args.output_filename
    output_filename =  re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','', output_filename)
    output_filename = output_filename.replace('@', '').strip()
    print('output_filename: {0}'.format(output_filename))
    connect_id = 'pul1pgdvpr87'
    connect_id = 'p6vwxp2d0c2f'
    connect_id = extract_connect_id(parser, args)
    video_filename = 'hello'
    video_filename = output_filename

    # ================ Download video  ======================
    output_folder = connect_id
    output_zip_filename = '{0}.zip'.format(connect_id)
    create_folder_if_not_exists(output_folder)
    create_folder_if_not_exists(main_output_folder)

    # Step 1: retrieve audio and video files
    connect_zip_url = 'https://my.adobeconnect.com/{0}/output/{0}.zip?download=zip'.format(connect_id)
    wget_command = 'wget -nc -O {1} {0}'.format(connect_zip_url, output_zip_filename) # -nc, --no-clobber: skip downloads that would download to existing files.
    run_command(wget_command)
    unzip_command = 'unzip -n {0} -d {1}'.format(output_zip_filename, output_folder) # -n: Unzip only newer files.
    run_command(unzip_command)

    # Step 2: create final video output
    cameraVoip_filepaths = []
    for filepaths in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(output_folder, 'cameraVoip_*.flv'))):
        cameraVoip_filepaths.append(filepaths)
    print('cameraVoip_filepaths: {0}'.format(cameraVoip_filepaths))

    screenshare_filepaths = []
    for filepaths in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(output_folder, 'screenshare_*.flv'))):
        screenshare_filepaths.append(filepaths)

    part = 0
    output_filepaths = []
    for cameraVoip_filepath, screenshare_filepath in zip(cameraVoip_filepaths, screenshare_filepaths):
        output_filepath = os.path.join(main_output_folder, '{0}_{1:04d}.flv'.format(video_filename, part))
        #output_filepath = '{0}_{1:04d}.flv'.format(video_filename, part)
        output_filepaths.append(output_filepath)
        # ffmpeg command from Oliver Wang / Yannick Hold-Geoffroy / Aaron Hertzmann
        conversion_command = 'ffmpeg -i "%s" -i "%s" -c copy -map 0:a:0 -map 1:v:0 -shortest -y "%s"'%(cameraVoip_filepath, screenshare_filepath, output_filepath)
        # -y: override output file if exists
        run_command(conversion_command)
        part += 1

    # Concatenate all videos into one single video
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg
    video_list_filename = 'video_list.txt'
    video_list_file = open(video_list_filename, 'w')
    for output_filepath in output_filepaths:
        video_list_file.write("file '{0}'\n".format(output_filepath))
    video_list_file.close()
    final_output_filepath = '{0}.flv'.format(video_filename)
    # ffmpeg command from Oliver Wang / Yannick Hold-Geoffroy / Aaron Hertzmann
    conversion_command = 'ffmpeg -safe 0 -y -f concat -i "{1}" -c copy "{0}"'.format(final_output_filepath, video_list_filename)
    run_command(conversion_command)
    #os.remove(video_list_filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    #cProfile.run('main()') # if you want to do some profiling
```

Comment: Didn't try nor read as I won't need this anymore. I accepted the answer as it seems elaborate.

Comment: The script does not work well! It created a 3-hour video of a 10-hour webinar! Also, the step #1 needs to be edited because of the default link there.

Comment: Same problem here as @mini. Anyone figure out a solution to this yet?