# How to download an Adobe connect recorded meeting when not the host?

Tags: video, download, adobe-connect

How to download an  Adobe connect recorded meeting when not the host?

---

I know that as the host, I could download a Adobe connect recorded meeting follows: go to https://my.adobeconnect.com > Meetings > select your meeting > Recording > Select your recording > Actions > Make Offline.

[image]

Comment: Unless the host makes it available you to, you cannot.

Comment: @music2myear How about using some stream capture program, e.g. streamtransport?

Comment: That would very likely be going against the ToS, and would be subject to someone having developed such a tool, which would make this a Software Recommendation request.

Comment: @music2myear I was simply giving one idea, hinting that "you cannot" was a bit shortsighted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download Adobe Connect videos to mp4 or speed up listening?](https://superuser.com/questions/1254845/how-can-i-download-adobe-connect-videos-to-mp4-or-speed-up-listening)

Comment: @music2myear Turns out your first comment was incorrect. [One can download an Adobe connect recording without being the host](https://superuser.com/a/1403970/116475).

Comment: Glad you found the solution.